# How to create customized menu inside a layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to create a customized menu and put that menu in a specific layout that is in the center of the *RelativeLayout*, i tried to make it like that but didn't work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Home" >

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid1"
        android:layout_width="750dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/Main"
          android:title="@string/main"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/Sub"
          android:title="@string/sub"/> 
   </menu>

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**in Java:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_home);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

**P.s** I also tried to make it in a separate file then add it but when doing that it only shown in the actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use menu directly into your layout. Instead create a menu layout in res/menu folder. And then inflate it with **Pop up menu** listener inside any button click event. There is a fine example of it in the following link. 
You can also Use **PopMenuWindow** **class** to use customized layout as popUpMenu.

http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

1) create **menu.xml** in menu folder(/res/menu/menu.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_setting_menu"
    android:title="@string/menu_setting"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>

  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:title="Logout"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>
</menu>
```

2) create function **showMenu(view)** in Activity class

```
private void showMenu(View view){
  PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(Activity.this, view);//View will be an anchor for PopupMenu
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu);
            Menu menu = popupMenu.getMenu();
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            popupMenu.show();
  }
```

3) set **Anchor for menu** ,where you want to show PopupMenu

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.grid1);//You can use other view as anchor
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showMenu(view);// call function to show PopupMenu
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Put `android:showAsAction="never"` in menu items to show item in menu.
like

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:id="@+id/Main"
              android:title="@string/main"
              android:showAsAction="never"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/Sub"
              android:title="@string/sub"
              android:showAsAction="never"/> 
       </menu>
```

put menu layout in menu folder (subfolder of res)

Comment: when doing that, it displayed in the actionbar not in the specified layout